# Prove that there's no smallest or biggest number in the open interval $(a, b)$ ($a, b\in\mathbb{R}$).

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> There's no smallest or biggest number in the open interval $\boldsymbol{(a, b)}$ ($a, b\in\mathbb{R}$).

Here's my proof:

*Proof*. Assume that $s$ is the smallest real number in the interval $(a, b)$. So obviously we know that $a<s$. Therefore:

$a<s\implies a\color{brown}{+s}<s\color{brown}{+s}\implies \boxed{a+s<2s}\ (1)$

$a<s\implies a\color{brown}{+a}<s\color{brown}{+a}\implies \boxed{2a<s+a}\ (2)$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we can write: $2a<a+s<2s\implies \large \boxed{a<\frac{a+s}{2}<s}$

This means that $\large\frac{a+s}{2}$ is in the interval $(a, b)$ and is smaller than $s$. This contradicts our first assumption ($s$ is the smallest number in $(a, b)$). So our first assumption is false and there's no smallest number in $(a, b)$.

Now assume that $\ell$ is the biggest real number in the interval $(a, b)$. So obviously we know that $\ell<b$. Therefore:

$\ell<b\implies \ell\color{brown}{+b}<b\color{brown}{+b}\implies \boxed{\ell+b<2b}\ (1)$

$\ell<b\implies \ell\color{brown}{+\ell}<b\color{brown}{+\ell}\implies \boxed{2\ell<b+\ell}\ (2)$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we can write:

$2\ell<\ell+b<2b\implies \large \boxed{\ell<\frac{\ell+b}{2}<b}$

This means that $\large\frac{\ell+b}{2}$ is in the interval $(a, b)$ and is bigger than $\ell$. This contradicts our first assumption ($\ell$ is the biggest number in $(a, b)$). So our first assumption is false and there's no biggest number in $(a, b)$. $\blacksquare$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes, your proof looks fine to me.

Comment: Proof checks out. But maybe you should add explicitly that you used interval openness in concluding that $\frac{a+s}{2}$ and  $\frac{l+b}{2}$ are in $(a,b)$

Comment: It's fine. But to avoid repetition, perhaps you can prove a lemma that $a < (a+b)/2 < b$ for any $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a < b$. (that's also something might be regarded as obvious and not needing proof, depending on the detail level required.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct, and is the usual proof given for this fact.

---

*Answering as community wiki so this doesn't end up in the unanswered queue, but yet also have nothing of substance to add myself in terms of commentary or criticism.*